# Entitlement on MacOS

Tags: macos

Where can I put Entitlement?
Of course, they can be inserted as part of the `plist` file of the app, but,

1. can Entitle be created only for binary? (Single binary without app)
2. Can Entitlement be created for a file that is not binary and is not part of an app?
3. Is the Entitlement associated with the running process? (If so, how can I pull the entitlement of a process that is currently running?)
4. Can I put Entitlement on script? (Let's say Python script)